# npm run build is not minifying the reactJs project

Tags: reactjs, minify, react-scripts, npm-build

I executed the npm command "npm run build" from the reactJs App root folder and "build' folder is generated with the below output in the console.

```
    File sizes after gzip:

  646.8 KB  build\static\js\2.d370d4e1.chunk.js
  12.46 KB  build\static\js\main.fec451dd.chunk.js
  823 B     build\static\css\main.fc109ae9.chunk.css
  772 B     build\static\js\runtime-main.83c3e0c4.js

The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
You may serve it with a static server:

  serve -s build
```

Then I executed the command "serve -s build" and got the below output in the console.

```
INFO: Accepting connections at http://localhost:5000
```

I could see all the *.tsx files not minified in developer tools. Not sure what am I doing wrong and why the files in the below mentioned "js" folder are not minified .
[image]

**package.json**

```
 {
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.56",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.68",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.53",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "node": "^15.4.0",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "prod": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.12",
    "typescript": "^3.7.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The setup is obviously right. The thing you have seen was just the `sourcemap` which is to map to the source code (for debug purpose) that's why you can search under browser devtool.

Basically `sourcemap` is generated by default setup of `cra` in `webpack` configuration file.

However, if you wish to stop generating it, you can do it via CLI:

`package.json`

```
{
  "scripts": {
    // ...
   "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",
    // In case of using Windows:
    "build": "set \"GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false\" && react-scripts build",
  }
}
```

Then you would no longer see you code under devtool.

Comment: i added  "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build". When I do "npm run build" getting error "'GENERATE_SOURCEMAP' is not recognized as an internal or external command,"

Comment: Looks like you're using Windows, the command then would be a bit different. Have a look again on my updated answer

Comment: Yes I am using windows. Even after using "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false" as per your updated answer the files are not minified. In developer tools I could find all the full files inside "localhost:5000->static->js

Comment: Did you check your `build/static/js` to make sure there is no files `.map` (if there's still map files, your command doesn't work properly)? Also please keep one `build` command  script.

Comment: you are right, I could still see 3 map files inside js folder. I manually deleted those 3 map files and now in developer tools I am not seeing any raw tsx files. Thanks a lot for pointing out map files!. Still no clue why map file is getting generated even with "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false"

Comment: worked for me as well for windows, finally

Answer (score 0):

Install the React Developer Tools extension. Hover over the extension if it says you are using production build then your files are minified. As you can see the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEJuv.png) below. Also read about production build from official docs from react.

https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html